# Find and Replace in Google Script Editor

Tags: google-apps-script, editor, google-apps-script-editor

I have questions about the Google Apps Script Editor.

When using the Find and Replace menu in the script editor, how can you make your search case sensitive? There's no "match case" option. Is there some way with regular expressions?

[image]

I'm working on a rather small screen and since the search is normally *not* case sensitive I can't see when it's locating what I'm looking for.

I was also wondering if the Find/Replace popup is supposed to be moveable since I just end up highlighting text if I try to drag it. The "Find" popup in the Google Docs Spreadsheet app can be moved, I would expect this one to behave similarly.

Comment: I'm not sure why this question was closed as off topic, when #3 in the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) refers to "software tools commonly used by programmers", and the GAS editor is pretty common for GAS programmers.

Answer (score 3):

You can drag the find box right out of the way by clicking within the single line phrase "Find and replace" and then dragging away from the central area.

Unfortunately you can't use regex (AFAIK).

Answer (score 2):

There is no case-sensitive search in the editor, but it's been requested. Visit and star [Issue 1593](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1593).

The search window is movable, but you need to grab something inside the dialog container. I usually grab it by the caption, "Find and replace".

Comment: Nice, well that solves one problem at least.  I'll keep an eye on that issue then.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to not drag the window out of the way but permanently (at least while working that day) to the far top right corner with all of the wasted padding removed.
-Right-click on the window to open the menu, choose "inspect"
-In the window that opens, look up the domain text until you see

```
<div class="maestro-dialog" role="dialog"
```

-Click on that line in the DevTools
-On the right side, change the Style settings under .maestro-dialog to be:
*uncheck the padding line
  ADD

```
right: 20px!important;
width: 440px!important;
left: unset!important;
top: 0px!important;
```

The box moves and will stay there every time you open the search....so long as you don't close the window with the DevTools (of course, you can hide it, but don't click the top-right "x")